# Unable to resolve this error after consuming long time on this "Help Me There"

Tags: solidity

```
PS C:\Users\Jatin\OneDrive - nsut.ac.in\Desktop\Truffle\web> truffle migrate --network goerli

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\demo.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\Users\Jatin\OneDrive - nsut.ac.in\Desktop\Truffle\web\build\contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.8.0+commit.c7dfd78e.Emscripten.clang


Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'goerli'
> Network id:      5
> Block gas limit: 30000000 (0x1c9c380)


1_initial_migration copy.js
===========================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------

C:\Users\Jatin\node_modules\eth-block-tracker\src\polling.js:51
        const newErr = new Error(`PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:\n${err.stack}`)
                       ^
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
undefined
    at PollingBlockTracker._performSync (C:\Users\Jatin\node_modules\eth-block-tracker\src\polling.js:51:24)   
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:509:9)
UnhandledRejections detected
    data: { originalError: [Object] }
  }
} [ProviderError: ETIMEDOUT] {
  code: -32603,
  data: { originalError: { code: 'ETIMEDOUT', connect: true } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea what the exact problem is, but you should use another network. You will face all sorts of problems if you continue using Goerli - it's not meant for dapp testing and the network is deprecated.

I recommend to switch to Sepolia instead.